# Unclear question on hold

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Just curious to know what was unclear there: (now deleted)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991438/how-to-get-screen-coordinate-in-php

Comment: Problem one: It appears you didn't try anything.  Probelm two:  You have a PHP tag on the question.  The PHP community sees a higher level of questions where the asker doesn't do any research or try anything.  They are oversensitive to "help vampires" (search for that term here for background), and therefore drove a stake through your heart without delay.  Sucks, but you look like you're capable of asking good questions, so just be a little more careful around the little helsings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We talked about this a bit in the (now deleted) question comments, but I think it might be worth mentioning it here on meta.

*You* might think that you're being perfectly 100% clear.  You have a specific thing that you want to accomplish, but are being thwarted by not having any idea about where to begin with it.  That's fine.  There's nothing wrong with that.

The problem is that the words you're using to express what you're trying to accomplish make it sound like you're making incorrect assumptions or have incomplete knowledge.  You're asking to do a thing that is not possible.  Because the impossible is impossible, and you seem to be rebuffing *all* attempts to ask for helpful clarification, your question is unclear.

To be specific,

1. You refer multiple times to trying to address *pixels*, but you state your PHP application is running at the command line inside of a [terminal or terminal emulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) (like an SSH connection or a Windows CMD window).
2. Terminals can not address pixels.  Terminals are text.  You can address the individual character positions inside the terminal.
3. Even if a terminal is running inside of a window inside of a GUI, there is no reliable way to access that GUI (from PHP) so you can draw pixels.

You need to clarify the following things:

1. Read up on [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/135887).  Tell us what you're *actually* trying to accomplish.  What's your end goal?
2. Are you trying to draw pixels on the user's screen, or are you trying to draw characters on the user's terminal?
3. Are you *actually* on a terminal, or are you running this at the command line of a computer, with actual graphics hardware?  In other words, are you trying to engage a graphics mode?

Please consider these points and questions, and edit your question to make it perfectly clear what you are trying to accomplish.  You can then flag it for undeletion.

Comment: I agree my assumption of screen resolution being counted as dot pixel in terminal was wrong, but it was still valid for coordinates. Screen value is still counted in X,Y coordinates even in Terminal. My question was to output certain character _('Hi', in that case)_ at certain position of the screen/terminal. I didn't see any nonclarity in that, its just people started jumping on assumptions and GUI thing which was never mentioned. To Reply your questions **1.)** I am trying to print *Hi* in 500,200 X,Y position of the monitor screen. **2.)** Hi is a character. **3.)** No, I am in Terminal

Comment: The terminal is a thing from which there is no escape.  The terminal doesn't know what contains it.  It doesn't know it's on a screen, and doesn't know *where* 500, 200 on the containing screen is.  You can't get that information.  You can't draw things there.  All you can draw is *inside the terminal itself*.  And the terminal sure as hell isn't 500 characters wide and 200 tall.  Please update your question and use *realistic* numbers for the terminal window size (like 200x100).  How about saying "My terminal is X characters wide and Y tall, and I need to draw text in the center of it."?

Comment: thanks for follow up, learned lots of things. At least you provide some insightful suggestions. Cheers, have a nice weekend!!!

Answer (score 7):

#### Your question:

> Is it possible to get screen coordinates like X,Y in php ?
>
> I am using PHP in CLI and if I want to echo 'Hi' in certain
>   coordinates of screen lets say at 200,500 (X,Y). how can I achieve
>   that?

It could be quite unclear what exactly you want to achieve. At first you say you're using PHP in CLI, but without any example (I suppose it's not crucial here). But first

> Is it possible to get screen coordinates like X,Y

you ask how to get screen coordinates. But what coordinates? In pixels, in console (those would be measured in characters). The coordinates of cursor?

> I want to echo 'Hi' in certain coordinates of screen lets say at 200,500 (X,Y)

So actually, you want to get current coordinates, or write to arbitrary coordinates? Or both? I'm also not sure how to formulate it but **I would suggest**:

> Is it possible in PHP, using CLI, to get the current cursor position
>   in console? How can I change that position (for example to
>   right-bottom) and write some text in arbitrary place of console
>   window?

However, I'm not sure if it's what you want to achieve.

Comment: His question is still valid, because talking about 200,500 is not telling if you are talking about pixels or characters.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. If you do not show any attempt and/or any code that you've tried, your question will likely be closed. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of
>   the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't
>   work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question
>   checklist.

Comment: His question isn't asking for code, rather for the general direction.